# Difference between simple Python function call and wrapping it in cProfile.run()

Tags: python, profiler, python-2.6

I have a rather simple Python script that contains a function call like

`f(var, other_var)`

i.e. a function that gets several parameters. All those parameters can be accessed within f and have values.

When I instead call

`cProfile.run('f(var, other_var)')`

it fails with the error message:

`NameError: "name 'var' is not defined"`

Python version is

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because cProfile attempts to `exec` the code you pass it as a string, and fails because, well, `var` is not defined in that piece of code! It is using the variables in the scope of the call to `run()`, but since you haven't told cProfile about them it doesn't know to use them. Use [`runctx`](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#cProfile.runctx) instead, since it allows you to pass in the locals and globals dictionaries to use for the `exec`ed code:

```
cProfile.runctx( "...", globals(), locals() )
```

Comment: I've used the profiler so many times but never in a situation that would expose this issue... thanks!

Comment: This is actually the only thing that worked for me, thanks!